# There are $20$ females and $15$ males in a party. In how many ways can $15$ couples be created?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> There are $20$ females and $15$ males in a party. In how many ways can $15$ couples be created?

I think it is $P^{20}_{15}$ but I feel I'm wrong.

Comment: You think it is one thing but you think you are wrong?  How does that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to @David G. Stork, I'm assuming you define "couple" as one man and one woman.

You have an excess of women. To counter that, select(choose) $15$ from the total of $20$. This can be done in $\binom{20}{15}$ ways."Assign" a woman to each man:

- The first can be done in $15$ ways.
- The second in $14$ ways

and so on.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  You choose $15$ women, and then match each up with a man.  *BUT YOU MUST TAKE INTO CONSIDERATION THE NUMBER OF WAYS YOU CAN CHOOSE THOSE 15 WOMEN!*. This answer does not include this crucial step and is hence wrong.  (-1)

Comment: @David G. Stork Actually it does. "To counter that, select any $15$ from the total of $20$". Though I haven't explicitly written $\binom{20}{15}$, it is implied. I'll edit that in anyway to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Sorry:  it is *NOT* implied.  Not at all.  You wrote "select any."  No.  You select a *specific set* of $15$.  Then you must select a *different* set of $15$.  A NEW selection!!  Then you must select yet a *different* set of $15$.  A NEW selection!!  And so on.  There is nothing whatsoever in your "accepted" answer that even implies this, much less quantifies how many ways this can be done.  Furthermore, the OP has a reputation of $45$.  Do you honestly... *HONESTLY* think he knew how to calculate this?  REALLY?!?!

Comment: @David G. Stork : My bad, I thought it was implied. I'll edit my answer again. And honestly, I never thought about whether or not he knows how to calculate this.

Comment: @David G. Stork How's the answer now?

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming you define "couple" as one man and one woman.

The first man has $20$ females to choose from.  The second man has $19$ females to choose from....

Can you continue?